# How to make object move toward target, then toward another target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that I'm trying to make move toward another object, then back to the original position. I have two gameobjects set-up as target, but with this code it moves toward the object then never returns. The targets are public Transform variables.

I would assume the problem is that the position will never be exactly even with the target position because the speed variable is 20f, but how can I trigger the change of direction without knowing exactly where the object will end up after the animation completes?

```
if (isMoveUpAndDown)
    {
        target = upTarget;
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        testObject.transform.position = 
Vector3.MoveTowards(testObject.transform.position, target.position, 
step);
        if (testObject.transform.position == target.position) 
target = downTarget;            

    }
```

Comment: instead of `testObject = downTarget;` you probably mean `target = downTarget;` (in the last line... ) and you should place the `target = upTarget;` (3rd line) somewhere else.

Comment: Check if the two positions are closer than `step` (before moving) and turn around if that is the case.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: @J.vanLangen You can convert that comment to an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @Draco18s yes, but I'm missing too much information to provide a complete answer.